# query not perfect to get the required results.?

Tags: php, mysql

MYTABLE-:Every 10 seconds some data is inserted in to this table depending on the page clicked(*x,y,z*)

```
page | time | string|  timestamp

    x |  0   | load | 2013-07-24 18:45:02
    x | 10   | 0    | 2013-07-24 18:45:12
    x | 20   | 0    | 2013-07-24 18:45:22
    y |  0   | load | 2013-07-24 18:45:25
    x | 30   | 0    | 2013-07-24 18:45:32
    y | 10   | 0    | 2013-07-24 18:45:35
    z |  0   | load | 2013-07-24 18:45:40
    x | 40   | 0    | 2013-07-24 18:45:42
    y | 20   | 0    | 2013-07-24 18:45:45
    z | 10   | 0    | 2013-07-24 18:45:50
    x | 50   | 0    | 2013-07-24 18:45:52
    y | 30   | 0    | 2013-07-24 18:45:55
    x | 0    | load | 2013-07-24 18:45:58
    z | 20   | 0    | 2013-07-24 18:46:00
    x | 10   | 0    | 2013-07-24 18:46:08
    y | 40   | 0    | 2013-07-24 18:46:05
```

This is what I am trying to return by my query.

```
x,50      //x page has max time of 50 sec
y,40      //y page has max time of 40 sec
z,20
x,10      //if I do groupby,i dont get this parameter.
```

**NOTE:**No of rows returned is exactly equal to no. of load in the string field

Here,load indicates that page is loaded

What I am doing-:

```
$query="SELECT field,MAX(time)" from table MYTABLE where "this is where i get stuck"
```

UPDATE:
There are three links on my page..**X,Y,Z**.
I am trying to track user activity by inserting some value every 10 seconds.Based on this data I will map a graph.
The users behaviour will be random(say from x to y to x to z to x).So i need to map these changes.On load,time==0 is inserted and load in string field is inserted.

Am i clear??

Comment: I honestly do not get, what your output should contain and what not.

Comment: @Sirko:the outout will be 4 rows since there are 4 load inserted in my string field of table.These four rows will be in this format(field ,peak time).So for first x it is 50 and for the last x it is 10.But if I use group by,I dont get four rows,i get only three rows.Am i clear??

Comment: Why don't you split your output in two queries. It will be easy. If you don't have any other conflicts.

Comment: Ok, you explained what you are doing, but didn't give any rule. EG: there are 4 "load" rows, why (or based on what) the query should return only "x|10|load" as last row?

Comment: updating the question 2 min...

Comment: I think, I'm getting what you want. But currently I don't think it is possible with your table structure as it does not include any kind of ordering. So there is no way to know, that after the last load for x there is just the x-10 entry. You should add some global timestamp, autoincrement column or something alike.

Comment: for simplicity i dint include it in question,both of them are present in my table..

Comment: @Sirko:i hope i am clear now

Comment: what is x-10? last row...

Comment: x,10 or say x and 10...just a hypehen...main thing is to return data...

Comment: @user2617915 I think those timestamps are rather vital here, you should not omit them.

Comment: ok,just updating my question...2 min

Comment: You are still not clear what you want or may be you are not able to describe your problem here. what is load? sometimes x will have max page time while you have taken again x in last row, what value will have in that and what is that for. too much confusion!!! Be clear and specific.

Comment: So you want to know the max value for each (x,y,z)?

Comment: yes..but any of them can reoccur...so i want max time for that as well

Comment: @ShuklaJay:load simply indicates that page is loaded and timer starts....0,10,20,30.This time is inserted in to time field

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to add one more column, let's say `GroupId (int)` which indicates every new load as new group, and increment `GroupId` by 1.

Example:

```
GroupId | page | time | string|  timestamp

1|    x |  0   | load | 2013-07-24 18:45:02
1|    x | 10   | 0    | 2013-07-24 18:45:12
1|    x | 20   | 0    | 2013-07-24 18:45:22
2|    y |  0   | load | 2013-07-24 18:45:25
2|    x | 30   | 0    | 2013-07-24 18:45:32
2|    y | 10   | 0    | 2013-07-24 18:45:35
3|    z |  0   | load | 2013-07-24 18:45:40
3|    x | 40   | 0    | 2013-07-24 18:45:42
3|    y | 20   | 0    | 2013-07-24 18:45:45
3|    z | 10   | 0    | 2013-07-24 18:45:50
3|    x | 50   | 0    | 2013-07-24 18:45:52
3|    y | 30   | 0    | 2013-07-24 18:45:55
4|    x | 0    | load | 2013-07-24 18:45:58
4|    z | 20   | 0    | 2013-07-24 18:46:00
4|    x | 10   | 0    | 2013-07-24 18:46:08
4|    y | 40   | 0    | 2013-07-24 18:46:05
```

After that, you just can simply write this:

```
SELECT 
   GroupId,
   field,
   MAX(page) 
FROM MYTABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    delimiter //
    CREATE PROCEDURE REProc()
    BEGIN
    WHILE time= 0  DO
    SELECT page,  MAX(time)  as time  FROM table1 ;
    END WHILE;
    END
    //
```

Comment: there is no problem in doing this but can you tell me what is happening in this query??what is delimiter,REproc...new to mysql